# Loading html data in Web View?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

```
<p>kick 2 first look on republic day According to the latest update, the first look of the film Kick 2 will be released on 26th of January. Regular shooting of this film is going on at a brisk pace in Hyderabad. Rakul Preet is playing the female lead in this film and Thaman is scoring ...</p>
<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.teluguabroad.com/kick-2-first-look-republic-day/">kick 2 first look on republic day</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.teluguabroad.com">Teluguabroad</a>.</p>
```

how to display this in web view and i was getting it from rss feed? to display that content in the next view controller having web view?

Comment: You need to edit the question to let people understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Language used? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a html string and then you can load this on web view.

```
    NSString *rssString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>kick 2 first look on republic day According to the latest update, the first look of the film Kick 2 will be released on 26th of January. Regular shooting of this film is going on at a brisk pace in Hyderabad. Rakul Preet is playing the female lead in this film and Thaman is scoring ...</p><p>The post <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.teluguabroad.com/kick-2-first-look-republic-day/\">kick 2 first look on republic day</a> appeared first on <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.teluguabroad.com\">Teluguabroad</a>.</p>"];
NSString *myHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</body></html>",rssString];
[myUIWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Also notice that for every double quotes " used in NSString we have appended a single slash'\'. So that Xcode compiler can understand that these double quotes are a part of string and will not confuse NSString with @" "  identifier which we use in Xcode.

And in case you need to load this to next view controller, you can send the string myHTMl to next view controller using property and load on web view .